# Finding largest clique containing certain vertex

Tags: python, algorithm, clique

I want to find the largest clique containing certain vertex in a connected graph.
In the wiki it said a maximal clique can be found by greedy search. However, this can't ensure that you find the largest clique IMO. For example,

[image]

If I want to find the largest clique containing A, and I do this by greedy search, I may end up finding (A,B), which is smaller than another clique (A,C,D).

I came up with a naive way to avoid smaller cliques: First find all vertices that are adjacent to your starting point, and then for each of these vertices (let's call it x), calculate how many other vertices that x is not adjacent to. After this, delete the vertex that is not adjacent to most number of vertices, and check if the rest of them form a clique. If not, repeat the procedure until the rest of them form a clique.

I understand this is a silly question but I'd appreciate it very much if anyone can tell me whether this approach is correct or not.

Comment: Probably this question is better off [here](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @RodrigoDorantes-Gilardi Definitely not math.  CS, maybe, but not math.

Comment: The answers so far talk about maxim**al** ( = "ungrowable") cliques, which are not the same thing as maxim**um** ( = "largest possible") cliques.  Nevertheless your problem is NP-hard, since if there was an algorithm for solving it efficiently, we could also solve any instance of the NP-hard (Maximum) Clique problem simply by adding one more vertex, linking it to every other vertex, and then calling the algorithm that solves your problem efficiently.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, thanks. My friend showed me a counterexample of my method. It can still miss some maximum cliques.

Comment: Rephrasing @j_random_hacker 's comment, your problem of finding a maxim**al** clique in G containing a specific node N is equivalent to finding the maxim**um** clique of the subgraph G' containing node N and all nodes connected to N. So the problem remains NP-Hard. However, it is better to work with the subgraph than enumerating all maxim**al** cliques of the entire graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate all maximal cliques within your graph, then just check - do they contain given vertex or do not.

Maximal clique enumeration is *NP-hard* problem, that is, we don't know an efficient way to solve it at the moment. I have tried [MACE (MAximal Clique Enumerater, ver. 2.2](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/codes.htm) and it worked quite well for me (it worked on graphs with thousands of vertices). You can check the details in corresponding [article](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-27810-8_23).

EDIT
If you just want to check does the maximum clique contain a vertex or not, you can try [cliquer](https://users.aalto.fi/~pat/cliquer.html) to find the maximum clique.

Comment: The OP needs a maxim**um** ( = largest possible) clique in this subgraph. A maxim**al** clique C is just one that can't be grown by adding more vertices; a different clique (that leaves out some of the vertices in C) could have more vertices in total.

Comment: @j_random_hacker. It's true that maximal and maximum cliques are different things, but I think finding all maximal cliques is a way to solve my problem because after finding them, you can sorting the cliques containing A by size and pick up the largest one, though this involves much redundant calculation.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I am fully aware of the difference between maximal and maximum cliques. But if you need a clique that contains a certain node, you have to run enumeration - the maximum clique could not contain the required node, but you are looking for the largest possible clique with the node. Still, thanks for a point, I edited my answer.

Comment: @SiChen You can try MaxSAT for finding the maximum clique with a node, but it could be rather difficult to implement. For example, consider [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6ce2/c473be601c1030f1ec4fbf733718e2a2c75b.pdf)

Comment: @CaptainTrunky: You don't "need" to run such an enumeration -- you could alternatively delete the required node v and all vertices that are not neighbours of it, and then look for a maxim**um** clique C.  Finally, add v (and its edges to vertices in C) back to C, to produce a largest-possible clique containing v.  (Notice that adding v and these edges back to C always produces a clique, since we removed any non-neighbours of v before looking for the maximum clique.)